# d3 x.invert returning Invalid Date from d3.pointer. d3 v6

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I probably should be sticking with d3 v4 or lower it seems. Anyway, I'm trying to create a typical Area Chart to display stock data. But I'm running into a problem with a mouseover function where I try to get the nearest data point based off mouse location. Similar to what happens when you hover on a graph like on google or yahoo finance. But the main issue is a problem with my X variable I guess.

```
   var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
   var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
   var bisect = d3.bisector(function (d) {
     return d.date;
   }).left;

   // Create the circle that travels along the curve of chart

   var area = d3
     .area()
     .x(function (d) {
       return x(d.date);
     })
     .y0(height)
     .y1(function (d) {
       return y(d.close);
     });

   var svg = d3
     .select("body")
     .append("svg")
     .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
     .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
     .append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

   var focus = svg
     .append("g")
     .append("circle")
     .style("fill", "none")
     .attr("stroke", "black")
     .attr("r", 8.5)
     .style("opacity", 0);

   function mouseover() {
     focus.style("opacity", 1);
   }

   // format the data
   var stockDateObj = {};
   for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
     var stockDateObj = {};
     stockDateObj.date = parseTime(key);
     stockDateObj.close = Number(value["4. close"]);
     setD3Data.push(stockDateObj);
   }

   setD3Data = setD3Data.sort(function (x, y) {
     return d3.ascending(x.date, y.date);
   });

   this.setState({ currD3Data: setD3Data });

   x.domain(
     d3.extent(this.state.currD3Data, function (d) {
       return d.date;
     })
   );
   y.domain([
     0,
     d3.max(this.state.currD3Data, function (d) {
       return d.close;
     }),
   ]);

   function mousemove(e) {
     // recover coordinate we need
     console.log(d3.pointer(e, svg.node()));
     var x0 = x.invert(d3.pointer(e, svg.node()));
     console.log(x0);
     var i = bisect(this.state.currD3Data, x0, 1);
     console.log(i);
     var selectedData = this.state.currD3Data[i];
     console.log(selectedData);
     focus.attr("cx", x(selectedData.date)).attr("cy", y(selectedData.close));
   }

   function mouseout() {
     focus.style("opacity", 0);
   }

   mouseover = mouseover.bind(this);
   mousemove = mousemove.bind(this);
   mouseout = mouseout.bind(this);

   svg
     .append("rect")
     .style("fill", "none")
     .style("pointer-events", "all")
     .attr("width", width)
     .attr("height", height)
     .on("mouseover", mouseover)
     .on("mousemove", mousemove)
     .on("mouseout", mouseout);
```

The data above shows the creation of the x domain and the svg element that handles the mouseover functionality.

I don't really know what else to do considering I'm using d3 v6.

But this my error when i console.log(x0):

```
Invalid Date
```

Comment: The pointer function returns an `[x, y]` so you could try this: `x.invert(d3.pointer(e, svg.node())[0])` to just pull out the x coordinate as that is what you want to invert in the scale.

Comment: Right, thank you, I tried that before and I still get the same error.

Comment: ah wow, I think I might've typed d3.pointer(e, svg.node()[0]) instead of d3.pointer(e, svg.node())[0] all this time.

Comment: Does it work with that amendment?

Comment: yes it does, thanks